# How does this line of code work? D3.js opacity function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, opacity

Can anyone explain how this line of code works?
Its a part of a streamgraph, when I hover over one stream, the opacity of the rest change to 0.2. Its really the ? in the middle that Im not 100% of.

```
            .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
                    return j != i ? 0.2 : 1;
                });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a ternary operator, the conditional operator, short hand if, inline if, et c.

> The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement. It is typically used as part of a larger expression where an if...else statement would be awkward. For example:
>
> ```
>    var now = new Date();
>    var greeting = "Good" + ((now.getHours() > 17) ? " evening." : " day.");
> ```
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Basically, if `j` is not equal to `i`, return `0.2`, else return `1`.